# How to submit form values to GET Controller Action in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC form (MyAction1) that contains textboxes, dropdowns, checkboxes, etc. The form is generated using a strongly typed View Model. I need to submit the form values to another page (MyAction2) in the same Controller.

It seems like FormMethod.Get is an appropriate choice to submit MyAction1's form values to MyAction2's GET Controller Action? Maybe it should be FormMethod.Post to call MyAction1's POST Controller Action and then redirect to MyAction2's GET Controller Action?

Either way, the form values are not available in MyAction2's GET Controller Action. I've traced the code as well as used Fiddler to confirm this.

I'm fine with using jQuery to intercept the form submit. I've attempted this without success. There are quite a few form controls and so I prefer to not create the querystring manually.

How is this done?

MyAction1's View:

```
@model My_Web_App.Models.MyAction1ViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction2", "MyController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <!-- Project Name -->
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectName, { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectName, new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="well col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
            @Html.ActionLink("Submit", "MyAction2", new { Controller = "MyController" },
            new { hidefocus = "hidefocus", id = "btnConsiderSpecificModel", 
            @class = "btn btn-default btn-block", 
            role = "button", 
            type = "submit" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

In MyAction2's GET Controller Action:

```
// GET: MyController/MyAction2/
public ActionResult MyAction2(MyAction1ViewModel formmodel)
{
    MyAction2ViewModel model = new MyAction2ViewModel();

    model.ProjectName = formmodel.ProjectName;
}
```

Using this approach, `formmodel` is full of nulls, 0, and false values.  It seems that MyAction1 View is not passing the form variables at all.

Comment: FormCollection? what ancient version of MVC are we talking about here? i would expect:

MyAction2(MyAction1ViewModel model) { } or is this for POST only? not sure i have ever wanted to retrieve data like this in the GET method.

Comment: It is only one of my latest attempts. I know it's not right. Nothing 'ancient'.

Comment: I would try the above suggestion in that case, might solve it in combination with an submit button in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
public ActionResult MyAction2(MyAction1ViewModel form)
{
```

You have a strongly typed view and controller is expecting `MyAction1ViewModel`.

Comment: I think the problem is in the View. FormMethod.Get doesn't submit any of the form vars for some reason. Everything is null, 0 or false when the MyAction2 Controller Action gets called.

Comment: Can you please show your `MyAction1ViewModel` class ?

Comment: I was using the Html.ActionLink helper which creates an anchor link. It wasn't actually submitting the form, just linking to the Controller Action. I changed it to an `<input>` and the form vars were then available in the Controller Action. Your answer works fine. Thank you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `FormCollection` only works on `POST` request.

There are several methods to get the data on `GET` requests.

1. Why not use your already created view model ?

   ```
   public ActionResult MyAction2(MyAction1ViewModel model)
   {
       model.ProjectName = model.ProjectName;
   }
   ```
2. You can simple add the name of the variable to your action method

   ```
   public ActionResult MyAction2(string projectName)
   {
       MyAction2ViewModel model = new MyAction2ViewModel();
       model.ProjectName = projectName
   }
   ```
3. You can look in the `Request.QueryString` collection.

   ```
   public ActionResult MyAction2()
   {
       MyAction2ViewModel model = new MyAction2ViewModel();
       model.ProjectName = Request.QueryString["ProjectName"];
   }
   ```

Comment: I've tried `Request["ProjectName"]` but it is always null.

Comment: Why not use the MyAction1ViewModel ?

Comment: thank you. I think there's an issue in the form submit. Fiddler doesn't show any vars being sent in the GET.

Comment: I'm sure your examples will work on the controller side. I think the problem is in the View. For some reason FormMethod.Get isn't submitting the form vars. I've edited my question slightly to show how the View and Controller are coded.